# Referencing template syntax system in Play framework

Tags: playframework-2.0

I'm doing my first project using the Play! framework and going through the first chapter of the "Play for Java" Manning book.

In section 1.5, we build our first template inside apps/views and it's called hello.scala.html

```
@(name:String)
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Hello</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello @name</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

To reference this template, I'm using the following line in app/Application.java

```
public class Application extends Controller {

    public static Result hello(String name) {
        return ok(views.html.hello.render(name));
    }
```

I'm not super familiar with Java yet, and I'm trying to break down exactly what that third line means, word by word.

- Return ok --> returns the HTTP OK code, so far so good.
- views --> Does this mean to look in the app/views folder?  Or is it a reference for the views pathing stored somewhere else?
- .html --> Is this the data type?  A file name?  A file extension? If the template was called hello.scala.htm instead would this change?
- .hello --> Is this referencing the title of the file: hello.scala.html?
- .render --> Do all templates use this method?
- (name) --> I assume that this is referencing the parameter in the first line of the hello.scala.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key to understand how the Play template engine works is to realize that each view compiles into Scala object. You didn't write which version of Play you were using. In 2.3 you can look at generated Scala sources at the *target/scala-{version}/twirl* directory.

> views --> Does this mean to look in the app/views folder? Or is it a
>   reference for the views pathing stored somewhere else?

**views.html** is nothing else than a package where an object is placed. If you have the *hello.scala.html* file located in the views directory Play automatically generates directory *views.html* and puts your template compiled as an object into it. The *html* package is generated based on the template's extension. All templates with *.html extension will be placed under this package. For other extensions different packages will be generated.

Notice that if you create a view in *views/subdir/hello.scala.html* then the generated package structure will look like this *views.html.subdir*.

> .html --> Is this the data type? A file name? A file extension? If the
>   template was called hello.scala.htm instead would this change?

As wrote above it is used to generate a package. According to the [documentation](https://github.com/playframework/twirl) only html, js, xml, or txt are valid extensions.

> .hello --> Is this referencing the title of the file:
>   hello.scala.html?

In this case **hello** is the name of the object generated from your view.

> .render --> Do all templates use this method?

Each object generated from a view source file extends **play.twirl.api.Template1** where the declaration of **render()** is placed.

> (name) --> I assume that this is referencing the parameter in the
>   first line of the hello.scala.html

Yes, you're right.

In addition, you wrote about your familiarization with Java. Apparently grasping all the details of the template engine requires a little knowledge about Scala as well. Good news is that you don't have to know everything about it to use it properly.